# Error Reading Characters of string - VC++

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, kinect

I got "Error Reading characters of string error" in runtime. And it is not handling with try catch,

```
void process(const BYTE* pBodyIndexBuffer){
m_pCoordinateMapper->MapCameraPointToDepthSpace(m_pJoints[JointType_ShoulderLeft].Position, &p);
            dx = static_cast<int>(p.X + 0.5);
            dy = static_cast<int>(p.Y + 0.5);
            try
            {
                if (p.X < 500 && p.X >= 0 && p.Y <= 410 && p.Y >= 0)
                {
                    pPoint = pBodyIndexBuffer[dx + (dy*cDepthWidth)];
                    while (1) {
                        if (pPoint == 0xff) break;
                        pPoint = pBodyIndexBuffer[dx + (dy * cDepthWidth)];
                        dx -= 1;
                        dy -= 1;
                        p.X -= 1;
                        p.Y -= 1;
                        OutputDebugString(L"Moved \n");

                    }
                }

                m_pBodyEdgeswidth[ShoulderLeft] = getDistance(m_pJoints[JointType_ShoulderLeft].Position, p, distance);
            }
            catch (const std::exception&)
            {
                OutputDebugString(L"Error Occured");
            }
}
```

I provided the part of code. 
Here is the issue I am facing,

[image]

Please explain how to resolve this issue.

But sometimes it starts running without error. 
how I am passing is,

```
BYTE *bodyIndex = NULL; 
cm->getBodyIndexStream(&bodyIndex);
if(bodyIndex) process(bodyIndex);
```

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass a valid non-null buffer to `getBodyIndexStream`. You are passing null buffer, which satisfies compiler and will definitely fail at runtime. It is like:

```
int* ptr = NULL;
// Set value
*ptr = 120; // crash
```